# Removing gaps between line features with v.clean in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, qgis-grass-plugin, v.clean

I want to fill gaps between line features with `v.clean`. It works for the small gap (0,015m) but the 10-meter gap will not be closed.

[image: 1= 10m gap, 2= 0.015m gap]

These are my parameters:

[image: parameters 1]

[image: parameters 2]

Test available here: [data shapefile](https://we.tl/t-rVRoL6v5JF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following parameters worked for me:

- `snap` : snap lines to vertex in threshold

[image: result]